# Swappiness not working, set to 10 but 40% mem and 40% swap occupied

Tags: 64-bit, ram, swap, 18.10

I'm experiencing this issue since I crossgraded my ubuntu 18.04 from 32 to 64 and upgraded to 18.10. Swappines is set to 10

```
cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
10
```

but is swapping from the beginning and now I have 40% memory used, 40% swap used

```
free -m
              total       usado       libre      compartido  búfer/caché disponible
Memoria:        3837        1346         148          25        2343        2190
Swap:          2047         750        1297

cat /proc/swaps
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda4                               partition       2097148 769024  -2
```

I have 4GB ram and 2GB swap, not suspending or hybernating at all, is a 24/7 NAS server.

```
uname -a
Linux 4.18.0-15-generic #16-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 7 10:56:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The problem is that the root disk is a SSD so I don't want to swap until it is absolutely necessary. What could went wrong? With my previous 32 bit installation it worked fine, it swapped but not as much as this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: With only 148MB free (just below 4%), no wonder it swaps. Also, 64bit OSs are expected to need more RAM, which, in your case, translates to more swap usage.

Comment: But actual memory used is only around 40%. There is a lot of memory cached, but I don't know why...

Comment: Thing is getting worse, 60% swap used after 36 hours and increasing. No new processes started. 45% memory still used.

Comment: I think I've got it: amule-daemon. After a little research (with a little bit of luck) I think I've found that amule-daemon is caching constantly, so the free mem is getting close to 0 and the sistem is swapping. I've disabled the service and now it seems that the memory is much more stable. I'll keep it in observation.